# Computation of $\det(I+UDV)$, $U,V$ unitary, $D$ diagonal

Tags: determinant, orthogonal-matrices

$I$ is the identity matrix, $U$ and V are both unitary matrices, $D
$ is a diagonal matrix. Then how to get the determinant of $I+UDV$ efficiently?

Comment: Also, when you say "efficiently", do you mean in a big-O computational sense or in a work-it-out-by-hand-in-not-stupid-amounts-of-time sense?

Comment: I have tried a naive way: first add $I$ and $UDV$ together, then perform QR decomposition. Finally, the determinant is $det(Q)*det(R)$. The complexity is $O(N^3)$.